# Send custom emails when an item is added to a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, email

I am setting up a SharePoint 2013 website for my team, and part of the website includes a feature to fill out a form which then sends an email to our team with the contents of the form fields as well as a link to the list item (to view it on SharePoint). One of the biggest problems I've ran into in trying to do this is the inability for me to install SharePoint Designer (security policy) as well as create custom workflows.

Right now, I have the form set up using the Issue Tracker app. I played around with using a workflow to do the emailing, however I only have one workflow template available to me (Three-State), and all it can do is send out either static text, or a link to the list item. What I would like it to do, as stated above, is send out the content of the form field from when it was filled out, as well as a link to the list item.

I am relatively new to SharePoint, but I have been doing as much research as possible and most of what I have found leads me to needing to use SharePoint Designer. Is this the only way to accomplish what I am trying to do, or are there some other hacky workarounds?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: I now have access to SharePointer Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to Designer to create a workflow, your best bet would be to use an alert on the list. The alert can be configured to send an immediate email when an item is added to a certain individual(s). It will contain all the list item data as well as a link to the item.

I don't really like the alters myself, but given your situation, this would be the best approach until you get your security/policy issues around Designer resolved internally.

Edit:
With SharePoint Designer, you would want to connect to your site. Then you should see an option to create a List Workflow. You select your list and add an Email action to it. In it there are several hyperlinks to click for configuring the action. You would want to put in the email address, subject, and merge in all the list fields.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671(v=office.15).aspx) is a good walk through.

Comment: I will try the alerts and let you know how that works. The only problem I can see right now is that the email will have to be sent to a team email address which is broadcast to all members of the team. Currently there is no "team" user on our SharePoint, and I cannot create a user either.

Comment: I believe you can put in a distribution list or email enabled security group. If all else fails, you could send it to yourself and create an Outlook rule to forward it to your team address. You could also advertise your team to subscribe to the list RSS feed as well.

Comment: I just got access to SharePoint Designer... in a very roundabout way, but it works. Any idea how I can do this now?

Comment: updated with a general answer and a useful link.

Comment: So I followed the directions you posted, and then added an Email action to it. There is nothing in the workflow but the email action (configure to send to my email for testing). However, when I click Publish it says "Errors in the workflow prevent it from functioning correctly." But when I run "Check for Errors", nothing comes up highlighted in red or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Disregard the above. I got it working A-OK now. Thank you very much for the help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for your requirement . If you have a visual studio with C# expertise , with custom coding you can create an event receiver with item added event .